# LINQ to Entites grouping by columns belonging to multiple entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am performing a `SQL to LINQ` rework on code now.

I have to translate to LINQ a query like the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NUM, A.a1, GROUP_CONCAT(A.a2)... A.an, B.b1... B.bn... etc
FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON ...
       LEFT JOIN C ON ...

GROUP BY A.a1, A.a3.....B.b1
HAVING NUM > 1
```

Note that I omitted A.a2 on purpose in the `GROUP BY` clause. The query does find duplicate records differing only by a single field. So in MySQL I have to project (`JOIN`) the entities into a single row, from which those identical are merged (`GROUP BY`). In SQL Server, the above statement is crazily complex.

I believe this is a very simple task in LINQ to Entities but I haven't yet managed to understand how I can actually perform a join on a number of columns **from different entities**.

I mean that LINQ `group x by y into g` syntax requires a single entity to be object of grouping.

My query starts with a typical

```
from A a in db.a
join B b in db.b.DefaultIfEmpty() on ... equals ...
join C c in db.c.DefaultIfEmpty() on ... equals ...
```

But then I don't know yet how to write the `group` clause to include columns from different entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did my homework and found viable syntax. The following is valid syntax I want to share

```
from A a in db.a
join B b in db.b.DefaultIfEmpty() on ... equals ...
join C c in db.c.DefaultIfEmpty() on ... equals ...

select new {a1 = a.a1, a2 = a.a2 ..... c1 = c.c1 ...} into j
group j by new { j.a1, j.a3, j.a4 ... j.c1 ... j.cn} into g
where g.Count() > 1

select new ...;
```

Explanation: according to the syntax, as better explained in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/231164/Into-and-let-in-LINQ-Let-vs-Into) `into` clause "creates a temporary range variable which you can use in further operations", actually *resetting* the query syntax environment.

It means that despite every query terminates with a `select`, using the `select ... into` actually allows the output of the select to be automagically the `from` of a brand new query. The same can be achieved with parentheses.

The above code is a simplification. My specific query has 100 fields to group by (yes, 100), and this looks the shortest-hand syntax.

Chances of getting confused grow, but when you are required to group by 100 columns you can't do anything else.